# Only allow a single domain to register when using the Ultimate Member plugin in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am using the Ultimate Member plugin and I only want to allow email addresses from a single domain to be able to register. Here is the code I am using , which I've adapted from [here](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/62-block-any-registration-that-does-not-use-gmail-as-mail-provider), but it is not working.

```php
add_action( 'um_before_new_user_register', 'force_google_email_for_avnw_signup');

function force_google_email_for_avnw_signup( $args ) {
    extract($args);
    if ( !strstr( $user_email, '@anydomain.com' ) )
        exit( wp_redirect( add_query_arg('err',  'whitelisted_email_required') ) );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the developer of the plugin? Seems like that's the best place to start, considering this is in their documentation: https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/62-block-any-registration-that-does-not-use-gmail-as-mail-provider

Answer (score 0):

According to the [thread here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/registration-whitelist-email-domain/), that hook is now deprecated. The link in that thread unfortunately 404's so I can't further verify it. Instead they suggest using code similar to:

```php
add_action('um_submit_form_errors_hook_','um_custom_validate_username', 999, 1);
function um_custom_validate_username( $args ) {
    global $ultimatemember;

    $adam = $args['user_email'];

    if ( !strstr( $adam, '@domain1.com' )){
        $ultimatemember->classes['form']->add_error( 'user_email', 'You must register with a valid email address.' );
    }

}
```

**EDIT** After finding their repo on GitHub, a [quick search](https://github.com/ultimatemember/ultimatemember/search?q=um_before_new_user_register&unscoped_q=um_before_new_user_register) shows that that hook doesn't exist in the current branch of the code base. Also, their [2.0.4 changlog](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/#developers) mentions several deprecations:

- Deprecated old unusable options
- Deprecated old unusable forms metadata
- Deprecated old unusable member directories metadata
- Deprecated old unusable user roles metadata
- Optimized registration/upgrade profile process (some hook deprecated)
- Optimized some code parts, deprecated some functions